# Callback argument type becomes any if related prop is not explicitly set as undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

if anyone could help me with this I would really appreciate it.
I need the type of the callback function argument to depend on the presence of another prop so I use a union type for the different cases, something like this:

```tsx
type Props = {
  useString:true
  value:string
  onChange: (newValue: string) => void
} | {
  useString?:false
  value:number
  onChange: (newValue: number) => void
}

const MyComponent = (props:Props) => {
  /* Component body */
}

<MyComponent useString={true} value={'abc'} onChange={(newValue) => {/* do something */}}/>
// value type is 'string' and newValue type is 'string'

<MyComponent useString={false} value={123} onChange={(newValue) => {/* do something */}}/>
// value type is 'number' and newValue type is 'number'

<MyComponent useString={undefined} value={123} onChange={(newValue) => {/* do something */}}/>
// value type is 'number' and newValue type is 'number'

<MyComponent value={123} onChange={(newValue) => {/* do something */}}/>
// value type is 'number' but newValue type is 'any' !!
```

When the prop `useString` is not explicitly set as `undefined` or `false` the `value` prop expects a number as defined in the props but the callback argument type is `any`. I don't know if that is a bug or I'm missing something, if someone could guide me it would help me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a TS bug, see [microsoft/TypeScript#41759](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41759).  Will write up an answer when I get a chance (although as far as I know it will only say "sorry, it's a bug").

Comment: Thanks a lot! Knowing that it is something from TS and not that I am doing something wrong is already a great help.